# Interface в interface Java (вложенный интерфейс). Как реализовать?

Tags: java, интерфейс

Есть:

```
public interface Country{
 interface City{
   String getName();
   }
 Set<City> getAllCities();
}
```

Как правильно реализовать? Вопрос именно по interface в interface.

Comment: почему не наследуются ?

Comment: Если интерфейсом `City` будут пользоваться извне (на что намекает тип, возвращаемый методом `getAllCities`), то почему бы интерфейс `City` не сделал "полноценным", в отдельном файле?

Comment: Это обучающее задание, которое я не понял. Я бы тоже интерфейс City сделал отдельно, но нужно разобраться с interface в interface

Comment: Хорошо, предположим, интерфейс `City` должен обязательно быть внутренним (то есть вопрос по поводу архитектуры кода не стоит). Представленный вами код компилируется и работает (то есть вопрос как это можно реализовать тоже не стоит). Тогда в чём вопрос?

Comment: class USA implements Country {  ....

Comment: Так, и что не так с классом `USA`?

Comment: class USA не должен реализовывать ещё и внутренний City, если вопрос в этом.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Объявление внутреннего интерфейса влияет лишь на то, как вы будете объявлять его реализацию. С точки зрения доступа он объявляется как `public` и только так.

К примеру, для реализациии внутреннего интерфейса `City`:

```
сlass PaloAlto implements Country.City {


    public String getName() {

    }
}
```

При реализации интерфейса `Country`, наличие в нём внутренних интерфейсов ни на что не влияет. Вам будет достаточно лишь реализовать один метод:

`Set<City> getAllCities();`

Например:

```
class Mozambique implements Country {

  public Set<City> getAllCities() {

  }
}
```

Так как интерфейс `City` непосредственно находится в `Country`, то декларировать внутренний интерфейс как `Country.City` в возвращаемом значении метода `getAllCities()` необязательно. Компилятор поймёт и так.

Comment: Я затрудняюсь сказать в чём именно возникла проблема у автора. Автор говорит, что это обучающее задание. Надеюсь, мне удалось объяснить принцип работы с вложенными интерфейсами.

Comment: @RafaelOsipov Спасибо, то что нужно.

Comment: @Igor пожалуйста, Игорь.